# Release build variant failed with debugImplementation for "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing" library

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-testing, androidx

## Expected

*Debug* and *release* build variants of the app to build and compile successfully.

## Observed

In the *release* build variant the app does not compile due to the `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` library.

### Library implementation

*build.gradle (:app)*

`debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.2"`

The full implementation can be found in the [GitHub repository for Coinverse](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse).

### Error

The build fails due to unresolved references to `androidx` libraries.

i.e. `import androidx.activity.viewModels`, `import androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`, `import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle`, `import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope`, `import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels`, and etc.

## Environment details

- Gradle version: 3.6.1
- Android Studio: 3.6.1
- Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
- Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS 10.15.3
- GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
- Memory: 1979M
- Cores: 16
- Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
- Non-Bundled Plugins: com.android.tool.sizereduction.plugin, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, org.jetbrains.kotlin, cn.wjdghd.unique.plugin.id, com.developerphil.adbidea, com.google.services.firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app builds and compiles as expected in the *release* build variant when adding the following library.

`implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"`

This library was present in earlier releases, but recently removed as everything was working as expected in the *debug* build variant without it.

Now `fragment-testing` may be edited to use `debugImplementation`.

`debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.2"`

Comment: For code written in Java you may want to use `"androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"`. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment for the current version.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and easy solution to this is to block fragment tests running on release test jobs like:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    assumeTrue("Skipping non-debug test", BuildConfig.DEBUG)
}
```

[Here's a blog post for more details](https://medium.com/koala-tea-assurance/unit-testing-android-fragments-without-breaking-your-pipeline-66d6c46d7)